# Pandas Dataframe: Adding the occurrence of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains a list of integers that represent the occurrence of an event. I'm looking to add another column that adds the number of events within an occurrence.

```
d = {'Occurrence_col' : pd.Series([1., 1., 2., 2., 2.]),
     'Values' : pd.Series([101, 102, 103, 104, 105])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)


Occurrence_col  Values
         1       101
         1       102
         2       103
         2       104
         2       105

Occurrence_col Desired_Output Values
         1          1           101
         1          2           102
         2          1           103
         2          2           104
         2          3           105
```

I know it's possible to do this through looping, but what is a more pandas-like solution?

Comment: typo: `d = {'Occurence' : ...` -- should be 'Occurrence' according to the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#enumerate-group-items) in pandas >= 0.13.0:

```
>>> df["Desired_Output"] = df.groupby("Occurrence").cumcount() + 1
>>> df
   Occurrence  Values  Desired_Output
0           1     101               1
1           1     102               2
2           2     103               1
3           2     104               2
4           2     105               3
```